# Как добавить элементу новый тег?

Tags: javascript

Начинаю учить JS. Можно ли как-то `<li>` добавить тег `<div>`?
Например: `li.document.createElement('div');`
Чтобы было вот так: `<li><div>Hi</div></li>`.

Мой код:

```js
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerText = 'Hi';
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Создание элементов осуществляется функцией [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement)
- Изменение поддерева элемента может быть осуществлено несколькими способами:

  - присваиванием свойству [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) нужного **html-кода**
  - присваиванию свойству [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) нужного текста (для случаев, когда элемент не содержит вложенных элементов)
  - добавление элемента в конец списка дочерних элементов с помощью метода [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- Связанные статьи на learn.javascript.ru: [Свойства узлов](https://learn.javascript.ru/basic-dom-node-properties) и [Добавление и удаление узлов](https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document)

Таким образом, имея элемент `<li>` (созданный через `document.createElement`, либо изначально находившийся в html, полученный методами [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)/[`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)/[`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)) можно добавить к нему новый элемент `<div>` методом `appendChild`:

```js
let li = document.createElement('li');
let inner = document.createElement('div');
inner.textContent = 'Hi';
li.appendChild(inner);

// чтобы сниппент что-нибудь отобразил
document.body.appendChild(li);
```

либо добавив нужный html-код к свойству `.innerHTML`:

```js
let li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML += '<div>Hi</div>';

// чтобы сниппент что-нибудь отобразил
document.body.appendChild(li);
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать

```
var li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML += '<div>Hi</div>';
```