# Создание и уничтожение кнопки в JS без HTML

Tags: javascript

Есть задача создать кнопку непосредственно в JS, без участия HTML и повесить ее появление и уничтожение в зависимость от условий.
Собственно, как это сделать и задать такой кнопке координаты?

Comment: связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/773244/227016

Comment: document.createElement и так далее, вроде бы эти вещи описаны в любом учебнике по js, не?

Comment: что значит задать координаты? Абсолютное позиционирование?

Answer (score 1):

Всё просто.

```js
var value = true //условие появления кнопки, true - появиться, false - нет 
var btn = document.createElement('button');//создаём нашу кнопку

var textInBtn = document.createTextNode('BUTTON');//создаем текст для кнопки

btn.appendChild(textInBtn);//добавляем текст в кнопку

if(value){//в зависимости от условия добавляем кнопку в документ
  document.body.appendChild(btn);
}
```

```
 // удаление соответственно по необходимости:
   btn.remove();
```

Comment: Хорошо, с непосредственно созданием кнопки понятно.Далее неясно, как оформить создание кнопки в конкретном месте документа в зависимости от условий. Также неясно, как на кнопку повесить функцию, прописанную отдельно от кнопки.

Comment: Что за условия у вас? Как понять фразу "как на кнопку повесить функцию, прописанную отдельно от кнопки"? Поясните точнее задачу.

Comment: Есть некое условие, при выполнении которого на странице в определенном месте должна возникать новая кнопка. Нажатие на эту кнопку должно запускать функцию, которая задает глобальной переменной случайное число, в зависимости от которого должна выполняться следующая функция, выводящая на страницу текст, после чего кнопка должна пропасть.

Как непосредственно создать такую кнопку без участия html я понял, а вот как сделать так, чтоб она появлялась в нужном мне месте, и запускала вышеописанную цепочку событий, мне не ясно.